# Is there an R function that populates the lower (or upper) diagonal of a matrix (with diagonal included) from a numeric object?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a list of a total of 55 numeric values. I want to create a 10x10 matrix in which only the lower (or upper) triangular matrix (with the diagonal itself) is populated. I know that I can use `lower.tri()` to create a lower triangular matrix, however, when I use this function, it seems like data is not populated by row. If i use, `matrix(v, nrow= 10, ncol= 10, byrow= TRUE)` then the full matrix is populated instead of just the lower diagonal. I have seen solutions to a similar problem ([Fill lower matrix with vector by row, not column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319407/fill-lower-matrix-with-vector-by-row-not-column)), but in that example, they use only 6 variables, whereas I have 10, and that solution gets distorted for me.

```
v <- 1:55
m <- diag(10)
```

Comment: so I didn't understand what's wrong with the solution in the linked question. Please provide you desired output as well

Answer (score 0):

A simple trick can do. For example, to populate a lower triangular matrix by row. First, populate an upper triangular matrix by column(which is by default), then transform the matrix. And vice versa.
Because R fill matrix in column by default, just fill the transformed matrix first, and transform it back.
Code example
`m = diag(10)`
`upperm = upper.tri(m, diag = T)`
`m[upperm] = v; t(m)`

Comment: So how is it different from the answer the OP has linked in his question?

Comment: @DavidArenburg They are the same. From the question, it looks like the explicit codes for 10 variables and some explanations are needed to help understand the logic ...